# Viewing output of stopped Docker container

Tags: docker

It seems like there's no way to view the screen output of a stopped container (which makes logical sense, since it'd need to be running in order to poll for screen content). However, if you're working in a vacuum with a third-party image, how can you debug a failure to start if you can't access the screen output? Can you stream the screen output to a file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you notice the [`docker logs` command](http://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#logs)? It will print STDOUT from the container.

Comment: I guess that it didn't stand out to me. Is that logging being performed at the docker level (which the description implies), or actual console output? At first glimpse, it seems like it actually might be console output...

Comment: Docker captures the application process's stdout, which is to say the console output of the app. You can also check the docker daemon's logs (usually in `/var/log/docker` or similar), but I don't think that's what you're looking for.